# Many-to-many, but only between valid pairings

Tags: database, many-to-many

Picture a system that is used by a number of **Customers**. Each customer has a number of **Products** and a number of **Users**. This is simple to represent as three tables:

```
           +-----------+
    +------+ CUSTOMER  +-------+
    |      +-----------+       |
   /|\                        /|\
+------+                  +---------+
| USER |                  | PRODUCT |
+------+                  +---------+
```

Now, we want to specify that a customer's users can only use a subset of that customer's products. This could be represented as four tables:

```
           +-----------+
    +------+ CUSTOMER  +-------+
    |      +-----------+       |
   /|\                        /|\
+------+                  +---------+
| USER |                  | PRODUCT |
+---+--+                  +----+----+
    |       +---------+        |
    +------<+ CAN USE +>-------+
            +--------++
```

However, this is not sufficient to ensure that no join exists between a user belonging to one customer and a product belonging to a *different* customer.

We can restrict this in code or via triggers (when adding a join, check that its user's customer matches its product's customer). Or we can even not care about adding invalid join entries, but instead be careful when querying to only return valid entries.

But is there a way to represent this restriction just using table relationships (foreign keys etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to add a `Company` table. Create a `User-Company` table many-to-one with `User`, with composite Primary Key `User` and `Company`.  Then, change the `Can use` table so that it includes `User`, `Company`, and `Product`, with Composite Foreign Key `User`, `Company` to the `User-Company` table, and Single column Foreign Key `Product` to the `Product` table.

---

I'll leave above for history, but now that you've edited your question, examine the below.

```
        +------+     +----------+     +---------+
        | USER |     | Customer |     | PRODUCT |
        +------+     +----------+     +---------+
             \        /        \         /
              |      |          |       |
             /|\    /|\        /|\     /|\
            +-----------+      +-----------+     
            | Cust-USER |      | Cust-Prod |     
            +-----------+      +-----------+     
      Comp FK         \         /      Comp FK 
      (Cust, User) --  |       |  --- (Cust, Prod)
                      /|\     /|\
                    +-------------+  
                    | Can Use     |  
                    |  - customer |
                    |  - product  |
                    |  - user     |
                    +-------------+
```

Comment: I wondered where Company came from, and I now realise I've written Company instead of Customer in a few (rather important) places. Sorry! But I think "composite foreign key" is the concept I need!

Answer (score 1):

If the tables were

```
USER: UID, CID, ...
PRODUCT: PID, CID ...
CAN_USE: CUID, CID, UID, PID
```

Then

```
CAN_USE { CID, UID } ---> USER { CID, UID }
CAN_USE { CID, PID } ---> PRODUCT { CID, PID}
```

The CID (Customer ID) is best validated as a key to a CUSTOMER table.

Comment: Composite foreign keys, then? It's always the simple things that I seem to overlook :)